# Win8 App: Binding to a UserControl property

Tags: binding, user-controls

The textbox on my main pages is bound to a string property on my usercontrol which is a popup.  The textbox value is correctly displayed with the initial value of the string porperty however changes to the property do not update the displayed value.  How can I make this field observe changes to the property?

```
**MainPage XAML:**
<TextBox x:Name="textBlockStartDate" Text="{Binding selectedDateString,Mode=OneWay}" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=MyUserControl}"/>

**MyUserControl.cs**
private DateTime selectedDate;
public string selectedDateString {get{return selectedDate.Date.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy");}} 

public DatePicker(){
  this.InitializeComponent();
  selectedDate = DateTime.Today;
}    

// Update the value when a button is pressed
private void DayButton_Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){
  Button button = (Button)sender;
  selectedDate = (DateTime)button.Tag;
}
```